# how to filter documents by Object.keys in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I would like to filter documents in MongoDB based on the keys of an object of the documents, something like this example in javascript:

```js
const collection = [
  {
    "emailsandnames": {
       "john@email.tld": "john"
    }
  }, 
  {
    "emailsandnames": {
        "doe@email.tld": "doe"
     }
  }
];

const searchingEmail = "john@email.tld";

const filtered = collection.filter(obj => Object.keys(obj.emailsandnames).includes(searchingEmail))

console.log(filtered)
```

I tried to achieve it with this filters:

`{emailsandnames["john@email.tld"]: {$exist: true}}`

`"{emailsandnames['john@email.tld']": {$exist: true}}`

But they didn't worked

Comment: Have you tried dot notation for querying?

Comment: yes!, if you are talking about something like {emailsandnames.john@email.tld} i did but because its an email and it contain dots it doesn't work

Comment: Yes, I suppose that would be confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally considered an anti-pattern to store data in field names.

It is possible to query the existing schema using aggregation by first converting the {email: name} object to an array.  However this method will not scale well because it cannot make use of indexes, and will require a collection scan for every query.

The pipeline would be something like:

- convert the emailsandnames object to an array, store in a new field
- filter the new field for the desired match
- remove the new field

```
[
 {$addFields: {emailnamearray: {$objectToArray: "$emailsandnames"}}},
 {$match: {
      "emailnamearray.k": "john@email.tld"
 }},
 {$project: {emailnamearray: 0}}
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QIj9rut_c5J)

This would be much more efficiently queried if the schema were modified to store an array of objects with static field names, such as:

```
[
  {
    "emailsandnames":  [
       {  
          "email": "john@email.tld",
          "name": "john"
       }
    ]
  }, 
  {
    "emailsandnames": [
       {
         "email":"doe@email.tld",
         "name": "doe"
       }
    ]
  }
]
```

This would allow querying the email field with dot notation, like `{"emailsandnames.email": "john@email.tld"}`, which can be supported by an index, and can scale much better: